# No boost threads are available?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, boost

Platform: RHEL6.3 (Santiago)

Boost 1.55.0, compiled with gcc-4.4.7-glibc-2.12.2 (I do not control the our boost installation and compiles, I just use it)

I am trying to compile a C++ application with gcc 4.8.2 (glibc-2.17) using boost_thread.

in the makefile:

```
BOOST_VERSION :=
BOOST_ROOT := $(DK_ROOT)/boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7/
ifdef ATI_BITS_32
    libdir := lib
else
    libdir := lib64
endif
BOOST_LIB_DIR := "$(BOOST_ROOT)/$(libdir)/"

ifneq ($(BUILD_TYPE)$(BUILD_REL_SYM),rel)
    BOOST_VERSION := -d
endif

LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) $(BOOST_ROOT)/
LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) $(BOOST_ROOT)/include/
LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) $(BOOST_ROOT)/include/boost/

LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) /contrib/STLport/
LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) /contrib/STLport/include/

LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) "/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-glibc-2.17-tls/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/linux/"
LCINCS += $(INCSWITCH) "/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-glibc-2.17-tls/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/include/"

GCPPFLAGS += -pthread $(DEFSWITCH)_LINUX -fPIC
GCPPFLAGS += $(DEFSWITCH)_LINUX
GLOPTS += -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs
#LLOPTS += $(DEFSWITCH)CT_CC_STATIC_LIBSTDCXX=y
LLOPTS += \
    -L$(OCLCOMPILER_LIB_DIR) \
    -L$(HSASERVICES_LIB_DIR) \
    -L$(HSACORE_LIB_DIR) \
    -L$(BOOST_LIB_DIR) \
     -lrt \
     -ldl \
     -lgtest \
     -lsp3 \
     -lboost_chrono-mt$(BOOST_VERSION) \
     -lboost_date_time-mt$(BOOST_VERSION) \
     -lboost_program_options-mt$(BOOST_VERSION) \
     -lboost_system-mt$(BOOST_VERSION) \
     -lboost_thread-mt$(BOOST_VERSION)
```

Regardless of what I do, when make tries to determine dependencies, I always get

```
Generating Test.cpp dependencies ...
In file included from /home/p4/bg-lnx-dk/boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7//include/boost/thread/detail/platform.hpp:17:0,
                 from /home/p4/bg-lnx-dk/boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7//include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:12,
                 from /home/p4/bg-lnx-dk/boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7//include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from /home/p4/bg-lnx-dk/boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7//include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from ../../../../LoggingRegistration/LoggingRegistration.h:33,
                 from ../../../../Common/Common.h:17,
                 from ../../../Test.cpp:18:
/home/p4/bg-lnx-dk/boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7//include/boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:47:5: error: #error "Compiler threading support is not turned on. Please set the correct command line options for threading: -pthread (Linux), -pthreads (Solaris) or -mthreads (Mingw32)"
 #   error "Compiler threading support is not turned on. Please set the correct command line options for threading: -pthread (Linux), -pthreads (Solaris) or -mthreads (Mingw32)"
     ^
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The error says what to do. Add `-pthread` to your compile and link command lines.

Answer (score 1):

They are there, added by some included files in my makefile.  It didn't make a difference.

After much playing around, I was finally able to compile.  I had several issues, among them:

using STLport instead of libc++, mixing libraries built with gcc 4.4.6 and compiling/linking with gcc 4.8.2.

Once I stopped using STLport, and forced using libc++, not libstdc++, I was able to compile and link.